# What is the difference between these vias?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, via

I have marked them with red and purple. What purpose do they serve?

P.S. I am new to this, so please help me through this.

[image]

Comment: My query is about the engraving surrounding it.

Comment: Is that meant to be a comment about my answer? The etching around the red-marked via is what keeps it unconnected from the surrounding copper.

Comment: I just commented before I saw your answer. But it is clear now. Thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one marked purple is connected to the plane region on the top layer (assuming you're looking at the board form the top).

The on marked red is not. Presumably it is used to make a connection between traces or planes on other layers you can't see in this view.

Comment: There are "blind" vias that go from an external layer to an internal layer and stop there without making it to the other side and "buried" vias that only connect internal layers and do not appear on either external layer but they are complicated and expensive to make so they are really only used when the extra little bit of real estate you get on the unused layers justifies the cost.

Comment: @vir, from the view we have been given there's no reason to believe these are blind vias (but we can't rule it out either).

Comment: I have read that vias, can double as test points. Does this mean that red ones cannot be used a TPs as they are isolated?

Comment: @courageouslywin for a test point you want a nice big pad around the via. I wouldn't recommend either one of these as a test point, although they might be usable in an emergency.

Comment: So, the ones in red are **not** connected to the top layer.  Only purple ones are (like throughhole vias) connected to the top layer. I might be reiterating what @ThePhoton said, but please correct me if I understand something wrong.

Comment: @courageouslywin if it's etched around so it doesn't connect then it's not connected. If the copper is continuous between the surrounding region and the via then it's connected.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments @ThePhoton.

Comment: @courageouslywin You can use the one in red as a test point for whatever it *is* connected to. The fact that it's not connected on the layer that's visible here doesn't mean it's not connected at all; it almost certainly is connected to at least two other layers.